# Finding Local peaks and troughs in a Time Series using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using the following code to calculate peaks in a time series data across various assets. Peak is defined as any point in time series which is greater than its neighboring points. Based on the number of peaks I calculate a score in the code as shown below. The input_args is in this format and rc is size of input_args. This code works fine but takes a lot of time when I call it across assets for long time series. Is their a way to make this code more efficient. I am looking for a solution through which I can make a logical array to identify the points in time series which satisfy the condition of being a peak and then isolate them to calculate the score ?

```
Data:-
1
0.997
0.979
0.952
0.935
0.942
0.987
1.027
1.036
1.049

function [maxhill] = hill_calc(input_args,rc)
for i=2:rc(1)-1    
    if and(input_args(i)>input_args(i+1),input_args(i)>input_args(i-1))
    output_args_hills(i-1) = 2*input_args(i)-input_args(i+1)-input_args(i-1);
    else output_args_hills(i-1) = NaN;
    end
end
maxhill = max(output_args_hills);   
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the indices of the peaks easily as follows:

```
ind = 1+find((input_args(2:end-1)>input_args(1:end-2)) & ...
    (input_args(2:end-1)>input_args(3:end)));
```

Example_

```
>> input_args = [1 2 5 4 7];
```

gives

```
ind =
     3
```

meaning that only the third value is a peak.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have access to the built-in function [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) in the signal processing toolbox...

You can find peaks using the `diff` function like so:

```
peaks = [false; diff(diff(y) > 0) < 0; false]
```

e.g.:

```
x = 1:100;
y = sin(0.2*x)+sin(rand()*x)*0.2;
peaks = [false, diff(diff(y) > 0) < 0, false];
plot(x,y);
hold on;
plot(x(peaks),y(peaks), 'ro')
```

[image]

Note that troughs just require flipping the less than sign

```
troughs = [false; diff(diff(y) > 0) > 0; false]
```