# substract consecutive rows in a matrix and get the maximum

Tags: matlab

how can I operate with consecutive values from a column. As an example, considering this

```
time temperature
1     10
2     15
3     18
4     16
5     13
6     10
7     13
8     19
9     11
10    13
11    10
```

I want to create two vectors, one in the "temperature" column with the values that are higher than the previous and the consecutive ones (peaks), and the other with the corresponding times like this:

```
temp = [18 19 13]
time = [3 8 10]
```

after that substract the previous time for the next one, like this

```
s = [5 2]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: [`findpeaks`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html)?

Comment: If you have the signal processing toolbox then [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) solves this for you. If you don't then look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25998788/1011724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
temperature= [10;
              15;
              18;
              16;
              13;
              10;
              13;
              19;
              11;
              13;
              10] ;

 [temp,time] = findpeaks(temperature')
 s=diff(time)
```

Comment: Caveat: This requires that one has the Signal Processing Toolbox for this to work.  The duplicate post shows a more generic solution to achieve the same thing without toolbox reliance.